# Bad Nav::widget encoding in menu, how to solve it?

Tags: php, yii, menu, yii2, nav

In Nav::widget I write new menu entry:

```
['label' => 'My profile', 'url' => ['/profile/professional&id='.$userlog->id]],
```

All ok and I see the link in menu. On menu hover I see good url adress in firefox:

> /index.php?r=profile/professional&id=22

When I clik, it redirects me to

> /index.php?r=profile%2Fprofessional%26id%3D22

And I see 404 error. If I change %2F and other symbols to slashes, '&' and '=' - this url working.

I save menu file with utf-8 encoding, why I see url with %2F and other symbols? how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `%2F`, `%26` and `%3D` are urlencoded characters for `/`, `&` and `=` respectively. This is because you are generating the Url as a string. Yii will Url encode strings in the url attribute by default. You will need to use something like this to make it work

```
['label' => 'My profile','url' => [\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/profile/professional','id'=>$userlog->id])]],
```

Answer (score 1):

You are building url wrong. No need to concatenate parameters like that.

`url` will be processed by `Url::to()` so change code to this:

```
[
    'label' => 'My profile',
    'url' => ['/profile/professional', 'id' => $userlog->id],
],
```

Official docs:

- [Routing and URL Creation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html)
- [Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail)